# GWR- interpreting standard residual and local R-square

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geographically-weighted-regression

I have run GWR for a layer with polygons. For some features the Std Residual has high value as well as the local R-square.

How is this possible?

If std residual is high, the predicted value will be higher than the real, is it right?

So, the local R-square shouldn't be small as the regression didn't predict right the real value but the local R-square is high.

What is the misunderstanding?

Comment: I am not sure about the correct answer, maybe @whuber might help, R-square is a goodness of fit measure for the mean value against the modelled mean value and the actual values might be relatively more different than this mean, therefore larger standardised residuals. I think this is **similar** to conceptual difference between standard error and standard deviation.